# Displaying RESTApi information in html

Tags: html, rest

I am creating my own simple rest api. I would like to be able to display information from it onto a html page. For example, if you called a `get` request to `https://ip:3000/products` you would get a response like:

```
       "product": [{
            "type": "Type 1",
            "price": "price 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "Type 2",
            "price": "price 2",



        }]
```

So how could i call this request and make a website that lists all the types in one column and all the prices in another?

Comment: In what programming language? Make a HTTP call to the API. Parse the JSON. Do a `for` or `foreach` loop through the resulting data and output HTML.

Comment: My friend, congrats, you have successfully created your API. Now it's time to decide how to *consume* that API, most likely you need to make an ajax call to your API endpoint (google fetch or jquery.ajax): after retrieving the data you need to decide how are you going to be drawing the HTML: plain JS? React? Templating engine?. Good luck, you are on the right track.

Comment: @ceejayoz The api is written in nodejs and i want to write the front end with normal html and javascript.

Comment: @Davo I cant get ajax to work. And i think i want to use just plain JS for drawing the content on the page

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fetch function of JavaScript to display your API data nicely on the HTML page.

Here (https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data) you can find more information about it.

Or you can also retrieve the data via Ajax, and then display.
(https://hackersandslackers.com/making-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)